# How do I create light reflections that are visible on surfaces?

Tags: glass, reflection

I am trying to recreate dichroic glass and how it not only produces colored "shadows" but also how it REFLECTS light back onto the surface it's mounted to. As you can see in this image, i'm creating colored shadows, but i'm not able to get the reflections to show up as per the photo example below my rendering.

[image: Rendering Test]
[image: Real Dichroic]

Also, does anyone know how to adjust the color of a shadow or relection of light based on the angle the light hits the material? This is another property of dichroic glass i'd like to re-create if possible.